Fadeout in a scroll animation
So i have found this code, and i want to add some small fadeout to this animation. So on one scroll it goes through some frames, and i wanna add two things that i need some help with. So first of all, how to make it go through more frames on one scroll, and second of all, how to add a fadeout effect to one scroll? Yeah, i'm pretty stupid in JS for now.


const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 148;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width = 1158;
canvas.height = 770;
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );

  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
  background: #000;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
<canvas id="hero-lightpass" />



I did try several times to do it by myself, but i think i just didnt understand the code.

What have you tried and where did you get stuck? "I did try several times" is not enough information. Please checkout Help and take a tour

i just dont understand the code. If you can, please, explain how it works so i can do it by myself. I have tried just changing all of the numbers, basically. As i have said before, i dont know js well enough to even try to make my thoughts into life through it.

If you don't understand your own code (whether you found it somewhere or not) then how do I even explain it to you? Beside, you didn't provide HTML, I can't run your code to understand what it does.

i can provide html and css, if you need it, just ask. I found this code somewhere on the web long ago, and i wanted to revise and learn Javascript again by just trying to tweak this code. I will provide css(this is not needed, actually, but still) and html in a minute

changed the question, everything is provided now. sorry for missing info, its my first question on SO.

I tried your code, it's not animating it's changing the images every scroll; you can simply change the image source to achieve the desired result without any extra code. Also please checkout the link I put in the first comment (especially tour) to understand why you don't receive answer.

Thank you for your answer, appreciate it!

I see what you're trying to do—no worries, we all start somewhere in JS! Here's how you can add those two things:
Go through more frames per scroll: You can multiply the scrollFraction by a number (e.g., 2 or 3) to make it progress through more frames faster.
Add a fade-out effect: You can use the globalAlpha property of the canvas context. This lets you control the opacity of the frames as they’re drawn.
Here’s how your updated code could look:


const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 148;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
);

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image();
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width = 1158;
canvas.height = 770;

img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};

const updateImage = (index, opacity) => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear previous frame
  context.globalAlpha = opacity; // Set opacity for fade-out effect
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;

  const multiplier = 2; // Change this to make it faster (e.g., 2, 3, etc.)
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount * multiplier)
  );

  // Fade-out effect
  const fadeStart = 0.8; // Start fading at 80% scroll
  const opacity = scrollFraction > fadeStart 
    ? Math.max(0, 1 - (scrollFraction - fadeStart) / (1 - fadeStart))
    : 1;

  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1, opacity));
});

preloadImages();



What Changed:
More frames on one scroll:
Added a multiplier (set to 2 here) to make it go through frames faster. You can tweak it to your liking.
Fade-out effect:
Used globalAlpha to reduce opacity when the scroll reaches a certain point (fadeStart).
Tips:
Tweak the multiplier to control how fast the frames progress.
Adjust fadeStart to decide when the fade-out begins.
